# Accessing angular route in JBOSS 7 results 404 Not Found

Tags: angular, jboss, jboss7.x

I have an angular app that works fine serving local.

this is package.json

```js
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "build:prod": "ng build --prod --base-href=/widcp/",
    },
```

and in pom.xml of web I have this

```xml
<build>
        <finalName>widcp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.td.phone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>td-widcp-web</artifactId>
                            <uri>td-widcp-web.war</uri>
                            <bundleFileName>td-widcp-web.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/widcp</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I run jboss locally, and I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/widcp` angular app bootstraps and loads correctly, all js files and css files are downloaded and I see the app.component loaded.

[image]

The issue is when I go to a route, JBOSS thinks I am requesting for a file or document and will return Not found

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

finally I ended up with `usingHash` as below

app-routing.module.ts

`imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],`

and it starts working